# Fuzzy RDD and IV

Tags: nonparametric, stata, instrumental-variables, regression-discontinuity

I understand the close analogy between a fuzzy RDD and Instrumental Variables estimation. This is clearest in the Wald Estimator. Here is the Fuzzy RDD equation:

[image]

And here is the (manual) estimation using IV:

[image]

My question is: when implementing an RD on Stata, using rdrobust, and choosing a linear function (i.e. polynomial degree 1), will this yield the same estimate as doing the estimation (manually) using IV?

How will they differ? How can you ensure they are the same?